# How to make a xml file in opencart for edit and model and controller

Tags: php, xml, opencart, vqmod

I am new to Open cart and working with VQmod and tried this code for editing my header logo and some text.

```
        <file name="catalog/view/theme/shopitout/template/common/header.tpl" error="abort">
            <operation info="">
                <search position="Replace" offset="" ><![CDATA[<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></search>
                <add><![CDATA[<img src="image/data/my_logo.png" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></add>
            </operation>


        </file>
    </modification>
```

Now i want to write such code for edit a controller and model.

please tell how can we make such code or xml for model and controller.

Answer (score 0):

In between `</file>` and `</modification>` tags add:

```
 <file name="###File name with path of controller/ model file ###" >
      <operation info="###Operation Info###" >
 <search position="###Search/Replace filter###" regex="false" ><![CDATA[###Search Code###]]></search>
 <add><![CDATA[
  ###Add Code###
  ]]></add>
      </operation>
 </file>
```

Reference link: [Opencart Vqmod tutorial](https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/)

Comment: Reference link is invalid (produces 404)