# Edit a controller using XML file in Open cart

Tags: php, xml, opencart

My Code is in a single xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created using vQModerator's XML Generator by The Wizard of Osch for http://www.crystalcopy.nl //-->
<!-- (Based on vQmod XML Generator by UKSB - http://www.opencart-extensions.co.uk) //-->
<modification>
    <id><![CDATA[vQModerator Installation]]></id>
    <version><![CDATA[1.1.6]]></version>
    <vqmver><![CDATA[2.4.1]]></vqmver>
    <author><![CDATA[Nidhishanker Modi]]></author>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/shopitout/template/common/header.tpl" error="abort">
        <operation info="">
            <search position="Replace" offset="" ><![CDATA[<img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[<img src="image/data/my_logo.png" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" />]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/module/slideshow.php" error="">
        <operation info="">
            <search position="After" ><![CDATA[
            $results = $this->model_design_banner->getBanner($setting['banner_id']);
            ]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[echo "Testing Data to hold screen"; exit; ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file> 
</modification>
```

Now Friends the second file tag is replacing my search data always. Even i am not giving postion="replace".
where i am wrong please give me suggestions.

Comment: I would try to change all the positions to *lowercase*, that is `replace` and `after` and use lowercase always only. Then also for `search` do not split the search data into multiple lines. And the first replacement is completely useless as You can change the OpenCart's logo within administration...

Comment: Thank you @shadyyx sir, 
But what about second search even single second search is also not working.
i have tried all possible conditions like lowercase "after" and single line search but all in vain.
i am helpless.
Please suggest me something.
Where m i wrong ?

Comment: Is the search string identified? Can You check the vQmod log whether it contains some error(s) regarding this XML? If You go to `vqcache` folder and search for the file `vq_catalog_controller_module_slideshow.php` (if present), can You see the changes being applied to the source code?

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/22143613/367456

Comment: @shadyyx  I have checked it is also replacing in that file even the main thing is that the vqmod is creating a cache file but it is not doing appropriate changes,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your first file tag code. Most probably:

1. Wrong file location (`catalog/view/theme/shopitout/template/common/header.tpl`) .
2. Or mentioned search code doesn't exist in `catalog/view/theme/shopitout/template/common/header.tpl`

Proof for the above statements:

1. Move the second file tag to first - Working.
2. Or remove the `error="abort"` parameter form first file tag - 2nd file code Working

if you still can't find the error, then refer the section under the heading - `Opencart Vqmod xml file not working??` in  https://sankartypo3.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/opencart-vqmod-tutorial/

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Thank you very much @sankarV most probably this answer is useful but 
my file location is correct i have checked it two times and found correct
and the search code is also exist in file but sir i will check to remove error="abort" may be it will work.
Have a nice day.